# Get value with in two separator in java

Tags: java

I have a string with `"_"` separator like `"A_B_C_D_F"`. I want to fetch the value after the 2nd "_" separator to 3rd separator. In this example the value will be `"C"`.

Please help me to do this in efficient way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String value = yourString.split("_")[2];
```

Answer (score 4):

Split your string based on "_" and from the resultant array, get the array[2] element.
That will be the output you need. Example to get it in one line of code is -

```
String str = myStr.split("_")[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.split` function like so:

```
String value = "A_B_C_D";
String splits = value.split("_");
String secondValue = splits[2];
```